# What does it mean to mod a vector by a set of points?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, integer-lattices

If $\vec{y}$ is in $\mathbb{R}^n$, what does "$\vec{y}$ mod $P(L)$" mean?
Where $P(L)$ is the fundamental parrallelepiped of a lattice given by the set:

$P(L)= \{x_1v_1 + \ldots + x_mv_m \ \vert \ x_i \in \mathbb{R}, 0 \leq x_i 
< 1\}$

Comment: I know what modding by the set of vertices of a lattice means, but not by the fundamental parallelepiped of a lattice.

Comment: Sure, what does that mean? I'm sure it would help.

Comment: It means to consider two vectors whose difference is a vertex in the lattice as the same point. The real line modulo the vertices of a lattice is a circle, the plane modulo the vertices of a lattice is a torus, and so on.

Comment: @Arthur What makes the parallelepiped 'fundamental' is that its points are a collection of representatives of that equivalence relation. Therefore, the mod just means to find an element $z$ of that $P(L)$ such that $y-z$ is in the lattice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In rough terms, *modding out by a set* means considering that any element in that set is $0$, hence that you can add or subtract them and stay in the same equivalence class.

Formally: $$\vec{y}\bmod P(L)=\{\vec{y} + p\ |\ p\in P(L)\}$$

and two vectors $\vec{y}$ and $\vec{y}'$ are said to be congruent $\bmod P(L)$ when $\vec{y}\bmod P(L)=\vec{y}'\bmod P(L)$, **which is equivalent to $\vec{y}-\vec{y}'\in P(L)$ if $P(L)$ is a subgroup of the ambient additive structure, here $\Bbb R^n$.**

This last sentence is the reason why it makes much more sense in general to mod out by the lattice itself rather than a fundamental parallelepiped.

Note also that if $P(L)$ was not a subgroup, then congruence $\bmod P(L)$ defined by $$\vec{y}\equiv \vec{y}'\pmod {P(L)}\Longleftrightarrow  \vec{y}'\in \vec{y}\bmod P(L)$$ would not be an equivalence relation.

Comment: Thank you very much. Out of curiousity, If we have $\vec{y}$-$\vec{y}$ mod $P(L)$, does this mean it's just the set $\{p\ |\ p\in P(L)\}$

Comment: @Maximus Absolutely (assuming that it was your intention to write $\vec y$ twice and not some $\vec y$').

Comment: Yes, I am reading a paper which says $\vec{y}$ is in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and that  $\vec{y} -(\vec{y}  mod P(L)) \in L$, but this is just $p \in P(L) $ which is definitely not in the lattice, correct?

Comment: @Maximus unless the paper does not use clear notations and means $\bmod L$ instead. Like I said in the answer, this would make more sense.

Comment: Thank you very much. Would you happen to have any reference you could give me for the definition you provided me with? He says $\vec{y}-\vec{y}\bmod P(L) \in L$ and then asserts $\lVert{\vec{y}\bmod P(L)}\rVert \leq diamP(L)$, so doesn't this definitely mean that he means P(L) and not L?

Comment: The last inequality would tend to imply that $\vec y \bmod P(L)$ is an element of $P(L)$, which would still mean that he considers a $\bmod L$ structure, only $\vec y \bmod P(L)$ does not represent the whole equivalence class, but rather the only element from the equivalence class that lies in the fundamental domain. Like saying that $47\bmod 2$ is not the set of all odd integers, but is $1$.